# Tracking header dependencies in Ada?

Tags: dependencies, documentation-generation, ada

Is there a tool that will track/graph header dependencies from Ada source code?

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming that by "header dependencies" you mean "package dependencies".)

The GNAT compilation systems comes with the [gnatls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/The-GNAT-Library-Browser-gnatls.html#The-GNAT-Library-Browser-gnatls) tool, which when invoked with the -d and -s switches provides the list of files upon which a given unit depends.

I would expect this to be a pretty standard feature of other Ada IDEs as well, such as Aonix and Rational Apex.

[Understand 2.0](http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/), from [Scientific Toolworks](http://www.scitools.com) is a commercial code analysis and browsing tool that would do this. It's a bit pricey, but that's because it is extremely powerful and worth every penny if you've got the budget resources. <plug>I don't tackle any kind of legacy code base without it.</plug>